# Behaviour of GCD in iOS and Command Line application

Tags: ios, macos, grand-central-dispatch

Sorry for the vague title due to lack of better concise.
I have two following codes here, first is for iOS and second is for Command Line

**iOS**

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSArray *array  = @[@"Hello",@"World",@"Hola",@"Mundo"];
    for (NSString *str in array) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            sleep(2);
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                NSLog(@"%@",str);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

**Command-Line**

```
@autoreleasepool {
        NSArray *array  = @[@"Hello",@"World",@"Hola",@"Mundo"];
        for (NSString *str in array) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                sleep(2);
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    NSLog(@"%@",str);
                });
            });
        }

    }
```

Both are same code

In iOS app when I press the button I am getting output after two seconds. When I run the mac application nothing happens. No output. Why is that?

**EDIT**

As holex said in comments

*A command line tool does not have a runloop and completes as soon as the code reaches the end of main*

Comment: Does the action method get called?

Comment: you must have specified whether it is a _Cocoa Application_ or a _command-line tool_ or what you are dealing with on OSX.

Comment: @holex sorry still a newbie in iOS. Sometimes I forget and sometime I don't see the obvious points. Will work on it. Promise.

Comment: Never use `sleep()` for anything, ever. See `dispatch_after()`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably You should dispatch queue by calling:

```
dispatch_main();
```

in main thread to allow main queue working. Be sure that after entering to `dispatch_main();` program never returns, so create thread or timer where you will write the code before entering this function.

Answer (score 0):

for **OSX** and **iOS** that works properly, I'm not sure which idea you are looking for, so I made code for both concepts which could make perfect sense on their own way in different scenarios.

## #1.

a new item is logged in 2 secs' time:

```
NSArray *array  = @[@"Hello",@"World",@"Hola",@"Mundo"];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    for (NSString *str in array) {
        sleep(2); // waits between iterations
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"%@",str);
        });
    }
});
```

---

## #2.

all items logged in one session after 2 secs delay:

```
NSArray *array  = @[@"Hello",@"World",@"Hola",@"Mundo"];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    sleep(2); // waits before iterates
    for (NSString *str in array) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"%@",str);
        });
    }
});
```

---

*NOTE: you can spot I distracted the entire fast-enumeration to a background thread in both cases, not only the iteration's core as you did in your OP; you need to be sure only that your app triggers the actual snippet, then it functions fully.*

Comment: the sleep was just for experimentation purpose. However both the codes are not working for the mac application but working for iOS application. Maybe some fault in Xcode (which seems unreal to me).

Comment: I have tested these snippets on iOS and OSX as well; I can confirm to you that these are fully functioning codes on both platforms. e.g. you could paste it into the _AppDelegate_ class's `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method on OSX to see those in action automatically after lunch, that is an idea if you are not sure how you could execute them and see them in action on OSX.

Comment: ok ... wait I am not understanding. iOS app has AppDelegate but OS X has only the main.m file . And yes the code is executing in AppDelegate too.

Comment: a Cocoa Application has standard `AppDelegate` class; that concept is not working with command-line tools.

Comment: lol. Never made a Cocoa app for os x. Ok. So is there any reason for the code to be not working in command line tool?

Comment: A command line tool does not have a runloop and completes as soon as the code reaches the end of main